# How to reinstall programm without removing it? All programms? Resetting configs?

Tags: command-line, apt

How to reinstall programm without removing it?
All programms?
Resetting configs?

Comment: Actually the programs don't tell ubuntu where they put the config files. But have a look at `dpkg-reconfigure`

Answer (score 0):

Software center no longer appears to have the re-install button.  In command line:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install program-name
```

Comment: and what does force mean? -f ? someone told me that that is doing it but it didnt so i was confused. -f is wrong for that yes?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `sudo apt-get install <app_name>` It will install that app as all of us know that .

If you do `sudo apt-get remove <app_name>` , then it will remove only that app but not its config files which are most probably in your home folder as Hidden files .

If you do `sudo apt-get purge <app_name>` , Then along with application ,its config also append to delete here .

So If you'd like to remove only application and keep those config files for future advantage then you must go for `apt-get remove` .

Man pages for more information:

**remove :** remove is identical to install except that packages are removed
           instead of installed. Note the removing a package leaves its
           configuration files in system. If a plus sign is appended to the
           package name (with no intervening space), the identified package
           will be installed instead of removed.

**purge :**
           purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
           purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

Comment: thats about installing and removing but not about question witch is about reinstalling without removing